# A sound effect on the acoustic guitar

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

It can be heard, for example,

- [in the intro of Ed Sheeran's "The A Team", 0:34](https://youtu.be/cOwsttzkUgs?t=34s),
- [in the middle of the Queen's guitar solo of "Love of My Life", 2:54](https://youtu.be/jO9C7frk2ss?t=2m54s).

What's the name of this short bright sound and how to produce it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bright sound (it needn't be short) is called "harmonics", and it can be produced by putting a finger lightly on a nodal point of an open string- that is, some small fraction of the length (a half, a third, a quarter...) and plucking that string.  This will result in a note an octave higher than the open string (if you touch the string halfway), an octave and a fifth higher (third way), two octaves higher (fourth way), and so forth up the harmonic series.

Comment: Natural harmonics to be precise

Answer (score 3):

They're harmonics, but they don't HAVE to be from open strings, (these examples are), although they're the easiest to produce. Best sounding when plucked very close to the bridge. If a string is fretted, you can use the thumb at the node (any of them) and pluck the note, usually with your pick. They're called pinched harmonics, and are most often heard on electric guitar tracks.